# Как правильно сортировать связаные модели?

Tags: yii2, relation, сортировка

Есть две модели `Goods` и `Price` связаны они через модель `Goods` так

```
public function getPrice(){
    return $this->hasOne(Price::className(),['id'=>'id_price']);
}
```

Я так получаю товары

```
$goods=Goods::find()->with('price');
```

теперь  мне надо отсортировать  `goods` по значению `price` модели `Price`
Затем я использую `Listviews`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$goods = Goods::find()->with([
      'price' => function ($query) {
          $query->orderBy(['attribute' => SORT_DESC]); //Или SORT_ASC
      },
]);
```

Где **attribute** - атрибут из таблицы Price

Можете также прописывать различные условия и все остальное, связанное с AR, например:

```
$goods = Goods::find()->with([
      'price' => function ($query) {
          $query->orderBy(['attribute' => SORT_DESC]); //Или SORT_ASC
          $query->andWhere(['active' => '1']);
      },
]);
```